# Hyperledger Fabric chaincode - could not import github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts, hyperledger-chaincode

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric and when I followed the [Hyperledger Fabric chaincode tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/chaincode4ade.html#:%7E:text=manages%20simple%20%E2%80%9Cassets%E2%80%9D.-,Asset%20Transfer%20Chaincode,-Our%20application%20is), the go importing failed as below. How to solve it? Thank you! The Hyperledger Fabric version is 2.4. Go version is 1.18.

[image]

Comment: Have you run `go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go`?

Comment: @chresse  Yes I have run it under `/usr/lib/go-1.18/src`. But I checked that path there is no `github.com` folder.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like its more of a general golang question about dependencies than anything specific to hyperledger fabric, so maybe worth reading about go module dependencies for example https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-dependencies